# How to enable ListItemButton to use React Router v6 Link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm trying to follow the example given in the MUI's do of [Mini variant drawer](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#mini-variant-drawer) to make the left `ListItemButton` to work with React Router v6's Link element. The documentation wasn't very clear on how to achieve that with a router library. I tried several variations but could not get it to work. The CodeSandBox link from MUI is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/spetew?file=/demo.tsx). Can someone please show me how to enable the `ListItemButton` to work with a path like `/my-path`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Import the `Link` component from `react-router-dom` and pass as the `component` of the `ListItemButton`.

[props](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/list-item-button/#props)

| Name | Type | Default | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| component | elementType |  | The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a HTML element or a component. |

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<List>
  {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
    <ListItemButton
      key={text}
      component={Link} // <-- pass Link as component
      to={... pass a target path ...}
      sx={{
        minHeight: 48,
        justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
        px: 2.5,
      }}
    >
      <ListItemIcon
        sx={{
          minWidth: 0,
          mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
        {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
    </ListItemButton>
  ))}
</List>
```

[image: Edit how-to-enable-listitembutton-to-use-react-router-v6-link]

Comment: Is there a way to make a function component that wraps this?

Comment: @Jaap Can you clarify what the *this* is that you want to "wrap in a function component"?

Comment: I ran into the issue that something like function MyListItemButtonLink() {} gave horrible typescript errors.
```import { To, Link as ReactRouterLink } from 'react-router-dom'

interface MyListItemButtonLinkProps extends ListItemButtonProps {
    to: To
}
function MyListItemButtonLink({children, to, ...props}: PropsWithChildren<MyListItemButtonLinkProps>) {
    return (
        <ListItemButton component={ReactRouterLink} to={to} {...props}>
            {children}
        </ListItemButton>
    )
    
}```
This works but gives me a huge typescript error in Webstorm.

Comment: @Jaap Errors, or warnings? Sounds like you might just need to "fine tune" the props signature. This would better make for a new post on Stackoverflow since it's a bit off-topic to this post, you can certainly reference this post/answer in any new post you make though. If you do decide to create a post for this new specific issue feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look when available. If anything you'll very likely get more than just my eyes looking into it since people don't go looking for questions to answer in already answered posts' comments.